# MS Access 2007 Blob Image export?

Tags: image, ms-access, export, blob

I have a MS Acccess 2007 database where we have inserted jpg images as blobs.  I am looking for a tool that can export these images to MS SQL Server database.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried simply updating a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server (>=2005) with the binary data from the Access field (column)?

Comment: When you say "as blobs" do you mean you are using an OLE field or an Attachment field? Or something else? I recommend against embedding any binary data in a Jet/ACE data field precisely because of the complications involved. If you do need it, the recommended field type is memo and then use GetChunk/WriteChunk to retrieve and restore the data as plain binary code without the wrappers involved with the other field types. Or don't store anything but a path to the file system (vastly preferable, in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a programmer, write a quick code in C# using. You need to use **OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbDataReader**

```
OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\db1.mdb");
//create the command object and store the sql query
OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from image_table", aConnection);
OleDbDataReader aReader = aCommand.ExecuteReader();
//now read the data and dump it
while(aReader.Read())
{
    // your code here
}
```

Ref: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/01/ms-access-application-with-c/

## OR

1. [export your data to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045346/export-ms-access-database-to-sql-server-2008-express).
2. Using the SQL Management Studio export table to SQL query

Comment: Do you know that you can link sql server tables to Access and just run queries?